# Newbie Java question - Object array from overloaded constructor not returning the right values?

Tags: java, constructor, overloading

I am in the middle of an Addressbook assignment. It looks kind of like this...

```
public class addressBook {

    private String businessPhone;
    private String cellPhone;
    private String facebookID;
    private String firstName;
    private String homeAddress;
    private String homePhone;
    private String lastName;
    private String middleName;
    private String personalWebsite;
    private String skypeID;

public addressBook (String fn, String mn, String ln, String homeAddress, String businessPhone, String homePhone,String cellPhone, String facebookID, String personalWebsite, String skypeID) {
        firstName = fn;
        middleName = mn;
        lastName = ln; 
        this.homeAddress = homeAddress;
        this.businessPhone = businessPhone;
        this.homePhone = homePhone;
        this.cellPhone = cellPhone;
        this.facebookID = facebookID;
        this.personalWebsite = personalWebsite;
        this.skypeID = skypeID;
    }

    public addressBook(String fn) {
        this(fn,"","","","","","","","","");

    }

    public addressBook(String fn, String mn) {
        this(fn,mn,"","","","","","","","");
    }

    public addressBook(String fn, String mn, String ln) {
        this(fn,mn,ln,"","","","","","","");
    }

}

    //A bunch of Setter and Getter methods here for each
```

I later created extended this class

```
public class BanffMarathonRunner extends addressBook{

    private int time;
    private int years;


    public BanffMarathonRunner(String fn, String ln, int min, int yr) {
        super(fn,"",ln);
        this.time=min;
        this.years=yr;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BanffMarathonRunner[] runner = new BanffMarathonRunner[15];
        runner[0] = new BanffMarathonRunner("Elena", "Brandon", 341, 1);
        runner[1] = new BanffMarathonRunner("Thomas", "Molson", 373, 2);
        runner[2] = new BanffMarathonRunner("Hamilton", "Brandon", 278, 5);
        runner[3] = new BanffMarathonRunner("Suzie", "Sarandin", 329, 7);
        runner[4] = new BanffMarathonRunner("Phillip", "Winne", 445, 9);
        runner[5] = new BanffMarathonRunner("Alex", "Trebok ", 275  , 3);
        runner[6] = new BanffMarathonRunner("Emma", "Pivoto", 275, 4);
        runner[7] = new BanffMarathonRunner("John", "LLenthen",243, 1);
        runner[8] = new BanffMarathonRunner("James", "Lean", 334, 1);
        runner[9]= new BanffMarathonRunner("Jane", "Ostin", 412, 1);
        runner[10] = new BanffMarathonRunner("Emily", "Car", 393, 4);
        runner[11] = new BanffMarathonRunner("Daniel", "Hamshire", 299, 4);
        runner[12]= new BanffMarathonRunner("Neda", "Bazdar", 343, 3);
        runner[13]= new BanffMarathonRunner("Aaron", "Smith", 317, 6);
        runner[14] = new BanffMarathonRunner("Kate", "Hen", 341, 8);


        System.out.println(runner[3].getTime());
        System.out.println(runner[3].getFirstName());
        System.out.println(runner[3].getLastName());
        System.out.println(runner[3].getMiddleName());
        System.out.println(runner[3].getYear());
        //for (BanffMarathonRunner people : runner)
        //  System.out.println(people.getFirstName() + people.getLastName()+ people.getTime() + people.getYear());
    }






    public void setTime(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public void setYear(int years) {
        this.years = years;

    }

    public int getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return years;
    }



}
```

The system.out statement for printing the last name for some reason returns the empty string but the middle name displays the last name? Could someone please tell me why this is happening?

Thank you!

Comment: The constructor doesn't seem to be at fault.  So that leaves `addressBook`'s `getLastName()` and `getMiddleName()` methods.  Are you sure they are returning the correct data?

Comment: @KevinAnderson is right. Also, you should always first start with 1 or maximum 2 initial values in the array, make sure your code works, then fill more. BanffMarathonRunners indexed 4 to 14 currently don't help us or you with anything. Just a tip for the future, because short programs are easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're setting middle name for all as blank string here `super(fn, "", ln);`.

Thus for this either you need to add a parameter in the constructor `public BanffMarathonRunner(String fn, String mn, String ln, int min, int yr)` or add a new constructor and call `super(fn, mn, ln);`

Or set middle name explicitly like this:

```
runner[3].setMiddleName("Suzie's Middle Name");
```